# Firesbase firestore not working + Vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store my geopoints to firestore database but it wont work.
I created an array called `acctPosition` to store there the geopoints inside,
but in firebase i can't see the data, it looks like that nothing is stored.

How can I store the geopoints correctly?

The output:

[image: output]

The Geoloaction component:

```
    data () {
      coords: {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null
      },
      acctPosition: []
    },
    ...

    mounted () {

     var self = this;

     // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          console.log(pos)
          var acctPos = self.acctPosition.push(pos)
          console.log(acctPos)
        }
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      }

      let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}`
      // store geoData to currentUser in firebase firestore
      fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).set({
        acctPosition: this.acctPos
      }).then(ref => {
        console.log('work')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
```

Comment: I think the error is pretty straightforward. Can you do a `console.log(this.acctPos)` just before you try to save the data?

Comment: everything is fine but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous, so `fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).set()` is going to be executed before `getCurrentPosition` is finished.

You can push to firebase after `getCurrentPosition` is done:

```
mounted () {
    ...
     var self = this;
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          console.log(pos)
          map.setCenter(pos);
          var acctPos = self.acctPosition.push(pos)
          console.log(acctPos)

          let docId = `${self.currentUser.uid}`

          // store geoData to currentUser in firebase firestore
          fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).set({
            acctPosition: self.acctPosition
          }).then(ref => {
            console.log('work')
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
        }
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      }
}
```

Comment: to  a normal string?